# Android Emulator 7.1.1 white screen

Tags: android, android-studio, exception, version

My application is working on Android 8.1, 8.0, 7.0, 6.0 and 5.1.1 but when I open it on Android 7.1.1 there is no error but emulator shows just a white screen

[image]

Edit: For example it worked on 5.1.1 but now, 5.1.1 also looks white screen. Android 6.0, 7.0 and 8.0 always working

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand, but you seem to contradict yourself. In the first paragraph you say is works on 5.1.1, but in the second you say it used to work on 5.1.1 but doesn't any longer.

Comment: Because it is working sometimes, for example 1 hours ago i delete my application on emulator and reinstalled it , it worked. However, now i'm trying same thing, it does not work

Comment: Does it work sometimes, or does it only work first time?